# Mapping an array of objects nested in array of objects

Tags: reactjs, json, mapping

Apologies if I'm missing something basic here. This is my JSON, I want to extract the "tag" value form the objects in the "cows" array. I'm not very familiar with nested data and have been stuck on this for a while. I would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

```
[
{
"id": 5,
"email": "vinnywebdev@gmail.com",
"created_at": "2023-11-11T12:38:05.829Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T12:38:05.829Z",
"cows": [
{
"id": 1,
"tag": 34444,
"dob": "2023-11-09",
"breed": "CHX",
"dam": 34563,
"docility": 2,
"agression": 2,
"fertility": 3,
"calving": 5,
"milk": 3,
"calf": 2,
"user_id": 5,
"created_at": "2023-11-11T13:48:48.743Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T13:48:48.743Z"
},
{
"id": 2,
"tag": 12345,
"dob": "2023-11-01",
"breed": "CHX",
"dam": 23412,
"docility": 1,
"agression": 2,
"fertility": 2,
"calving": 3,
"milk": 1,
"calf": 3,
"user_id": 5,
"created_at": "2023-11-11T13:54:42.178Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T13:54:42.178Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 6,
"email": "test@test.com",
"created_at": "2023-11-11T13:21:01.869Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T13:21:01.869Z",
"cows": [
{
"id": 3,
"tag": 34444,
"dob": "2023-11-01",
"breed": "CHX",
"dam": 12341,
"docility": 1,
"agression": 3,
"fertility": 3,
"calving": 1,
"milk": 3,
"calf": 1,
"user_id": 6,
"created_at": "2023-11-11T13:59:11.224Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T13:59:11.224Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 7,
"email": "vinny@test.com",
"created_at": "2023-11-11T15:02:16.193Z",
"updated_at": "2023-11-11T15:02:16.193Z",
"cows": []
}
]
```

This is what I have come up with but it's not working unfortunately. The Cow component just renders the tag value in a p tag.

```
const ViewHerd = () => {

    const [herd, setHerd] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            // You can await here
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/', {
                headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
            });
            console.log(response.data)
            setHerd(response.data)
        }
        fetchData();

    }, []); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Herd</h1>
            {
                //iterate over outer array
                herd.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        //iterate over inner array
                        item.cows.map((sub) => {
                            <Cow tag={sub.tag}></Cow>
                        })
                    )
                })
            }
        </div >
    )
}

export default ViewHerd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are iterating through `items.cows` using `map` but not returning any value. To get the behavior you need, the return statement from your Component should look something like this

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Herd</h1>
      {herd.map((item) =>
        item.cows.map((sub) => {
          return <Cow key={sub.id} tag={sub.tag}></Cow>; // Adding return statement
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

**OR**

```
return (
        <div>
            <h1>Herd</h1>
            {
                herd.map((item) => 
                    item.cows.map((sub) => (
                        <Cow key={sub.id} tag={sub.tag}></Cow> // implicit return (no brackets)
                    ))
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
```

Also, notice that I added a unique `key` prop to each `Cow` rendered. In React, when rendering lists, each child should have a unique key. Otherwise, a big red warning will show up on the console. Let me know if this solves your issues! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I should have noticed that. Much appreciated.